# Disable Smooth scroll when jump current item to another item in viewpager2 android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-viewpager2

Hey everyone I am new in android with kotlin. I have problem in **viewpager2** which I cannot solve. I have one **Mutable list** in which 30 items data is present on it. When application opens I sat by  default 15 index number data as default as index of **viewpager2** as current item. If I move to page to 0 index then, I am reseting the Mutablelist data and adding 10 or 20 data on left and 0 index value set in the middle, which means I am shifting the data in which I am in successful. But the main problem is to disable the smooth scroll between 0 to 10-20 when I reset the list also I have **observable** variable as my current index which I am changing the current item of **viewpager2**.

```
private var b = false

 mViewPager.registerOnPageChangeCallback(object : ViewPager2.OnPageChangeCallback() {
    override fun onPageScrolled(int position, float arg1, int arg2) {
            if(b){
                 if(position > 0 && position < 15){
                    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(currenIndex,false)
                    b = false
                 }
             }
    }
}
```

In **Activity** when I am resetting the mutable list or adding some value on it I changed the boolean value as true

```
 b = true
```

also in my observable code

```
currenIndex.observer(this, Observer {
 mViewPager.setCurrentItem(it, true)
})
```

It always jumping when resetting the list to **0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10..** and I want to disable all animation between them and only wanted to display the page directly **15 page**

Also I tried to remove

```
mViewPager.setCurrentItem(it, true)
```

from my observable variable it works but their is some problem in between 0 and 1 the animation stops between them when first time to reaching index 0 without resetting the list.

Sorry for my English. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

The second parameter of ViewPager.setCurrentItem funtion is **boolean smoothScroll** Try this:

```
mViewPager.setCurrentItem(15, false)
```